# If $S$ and $M$ are Positive Definitive Matrices, Why $S$ and $M^{-1/2}$S$M^{-1/2}$ share the same eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra

Following and argument to find the solution to the max of the generalized Rayleig Quotient, $\frac {x^tSx}{x^tMx}$,  I found the stament:

if $S$ and $M$ be Positive Definitive, $S$ and $M^{-1/2}$S$M^{-1/2}$ share the same eigenvalues.

How can it be proved?

Comment: It is not true that $S$ and $M^{-1/2}SM^{-1/2}$ necessarily have the same eigenvalues (even if we know that both matrices are positive definite). Where did you come across this statement?

Comment: I misread. it was $M^{-1}$S instead of S. Those are clearly similar matrixes. Thank  you @Omnomnomnom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is obviously false. As a counterexample, consider any positive definite $S,M$ for which $S \neq I$ and $S = M$.